# Change Asp.net Core Route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

how can I change the default address of the controller to the desired address? For example change http://Home/main?id=2 to http://Home/main/my_text

Comment: Have you checked this doc about routing to controller actions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using attribute routing then below will be solution for that.

```cs
public class HomeController: BaseController
{
    [Route("/Home")]
    [Route("/Home/Main")]
    [Route("/Home/Main/{value}")]
    public IActionResult Main(string value = "my_text")
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Above action will execute for below routes and you will get this value.

| Route | Value |
| --- | --- |
| /Home | my_text |
| /Home/Main | my_text |
| /Home/Main/my_text | my_text |
| /Home/Main/other_text | other_text |